# Firefox 55.03 resize is resizing with selenium automation

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have recently upgraded the Selenium to 3.5, Firefox to 55.03 and Gecko driver to 0.19 version. All are latest.

But now when we execute our script, browser window get resized to small or even very small. I used:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

but it is not working any more now. With earlier version it worked fine.

Also at the end browser get crashed instead of closing.

Please help if any one else also faced this issue.

Comment: Please share the snapshot

Comment: Might be it is issue of GeckoDriver

Comment: Try using Geckodriver 0.18

Comment: Degrade the GeckoDriver

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Firefox no longer supports it from version 55+

This is from their [addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) page:
Note: Selenium IDE will NOT work on Firefox version 55 onwards. Please stay on Firefox version 54 or older.

Comment: since it is not a proper answer, it is better to include the useful info as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Remove the from the code

```
driver.close();
```

then try.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.maximize_window()
```